# Lucee on windows 10 - Client Denied by Server Configuration

Tags: windows-10, lucee

Lucee on windows 10 - AH01630 Client Denied by Server Configuration

Have tried 1000 ways to resolve this

Have tried everything I could find from searching the Internet for a week.

Anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

After trying 1000 different things from changing the Directory, to changing the Allow Deny schemes etc, I finally found the answer

I changed this......

```
<Proxy *>
# When using Apache 2.2, use the following line (without the "# ")
# Allow from 127.0.0.1
# When using Apache 2.4, use this line (without the "# ")
Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2
```

To this....VOILA!

```
 <Proxy 8009>
 # When using Apache 2.2, use the following line (without the "# ")
 # Allow from 127.0.0.1
 # When using Apache 2.4, use this line (without the "# ")
 Require ip 127.0.0.1
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2
```